# Unit test: Program ended with exit code: 82 App consist from modules

Tags: ios, unit-testing, cocoapods, ios-frameworks

My app consists from modules(frameworks) and i use pods for add third party framework. In pod file i add dependency for some lib only for target  that will be use this framework. Example:  i have `"Acount.framework"` and it use lib for keychain access and other modules dont know about it.  So in pod file i write

```
def userAccount_pods
    project '../UserAccount/UserAccount.xcodeproj'
    workspace '../UserAccount/UserAccount.workspace'

    pod 'Valet'
end
target 'UserAccount' do
    userAccount_pods
end
target 'UserAccountTests' do
    userAccount_pods
end
```

Also i have other framework  -"Logic.framework" and it use acount framework(in the his build setting i add  binary link)  and all working perfect. But i have some trouble with unit tests.

My tests for "logic framework" use "user account" (inside methods) 
and i have log:

```
The bundle “logicTest” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources. Try reinstalling the bundle.
Library not loaded: @rpath/Valet.framework/Valet
Referenced from: Acount
Program ended with exit code: 82
```

I know that for fix it i can add pod "Valet" in target - logicTest  but i  find it strange.

Please help me find elegant solution

**Thanks averyone in advance**